# Why my access to non static string variable doesn't work

Tags: java

Why my access to non static string variable doesn't work. Try to do it and my IDE found it already but when I run it show "Cannot find symbol"
Please help me, Thank You.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testWrong obj = new testWrong();
        System.out.println(obj.public_non_static()); //Doesn't Work


    }

}



public class testWrong
{
    public String public_non_static = "It is Public non Static";

    public void in_non_static_method()
    {
        testWrong obj1 = new testWrong();
        obj1.public_non_static();   //Doesn't Work

    }

    public static void in_static_method()
    {
        testWrong obj2 = new testWrong();
        obj2.public_non_static(); //Doesn't Work also
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `()`?......

Comment: Because its a public field and not a method. You are using the wrong syntax to access the field.

Comment: obj1.public_non_static;      shold be like this without ()

Comment: This question should be closed as it was a typo.

Comment: @Nathan you know the TO and talked to him?

Comment: TO -> "thread opener" ...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle His example does not respect the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): The question won't help any other user, as his code isn't correctly compiling because of a typo. So the question should be closed.

Comment: @Nathan While your reasoning to close the question is right you do simple not know if the TO made a typo or had a wrong understanding of how java works...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Whichever it is, the question should be closed as off-topic. This is simply because errors like his won't help other users. Flagging the question doesn't mean I don't like the TO, it's just for indexation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You have a **variable** named `public_non_static` but you try to access a **method** with that name which does not work in Java.

on the other hand you should not get used to access variables in other classes directly since it violates the most important OO principle *information hiding/encapsulation*.

The same is true for *getter/setter* methods which should only be used on stupid *data transfer objects* (DTOs) or *Value Objects* which have no (business) logic.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing like a method :public_non_static();

Use this instead : obj2.public_non_static;

And since you are like very new to OOP, it's the best practice to not to use public keyword and you should make them private and make getters and setters for them.